# Sockets with pthreads issue

Tags: c, sockets, pthreads

I'm creating a server/client echo program. The client reads a string, sends to the server and the server sends the string back to the client.

Data structures:

```
typedef struct writeStruct
{
    FILE *wsock;
    int sockfd;
} writeStruct;

typedef struct readStruct
{
    FILE *rsock;
    int sockfd;
 } readStruct;
```

Part of the main function:

```
main()
{
    writeStruct *writeData;
    readStruct *readData;
    writeData = malloc(sizeof(writeData));
    readData = malloc(sizeof(readData));

    pthread_t write;
    pthread_t read;

    FILE *rsock, *wsock;

    int sockfd;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    rsock = fdopen(sockfd, "r");
    wsock = fdopen(sockfd, "w");

    writeData->wsock = wsock;
    readData->rsock = rsock;

    writeData->sockfd = sockfd;
    readData->sockfd = sockfd;

    pthread_create(&write, NULL, writeProcess, (void*)writeData);
    pthread_create(&read, NULL, readProcess, (void*)readData);

    pthread_join(write, NULL);
    pthread_join(read, NULL);
 }
```

And the functions:

Write function:

```
void *writeProcess(void *writeData)
{
    FILE *wsock = ((writeStruct*)writeData)->wsock;
    int sockfd = ((writeStruct*)writeData)->sockfd;
    int success = 0;
    char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXDATASIZE);

    while(fgets(buf, MAXDATASIZE, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        fputs(buf, wsock);
        fflush(wsock);
    }
    fputs(buf, wsock);
    free(buf);
    shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_WR);
}
```

Read function:

```
void *readProcess(void *readData)
{
    FILE *rsock = ((readStruct*)readData)->rsock;
    int sockfd = ((readStruct*)readData)->sockfd;
    char *rcv, *rcvAux;
    rcv = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXDATASIZE);
    rcvAux = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXDATASIZE);

    rcvAux = fgets(rcv, MAXDATASIZE, rsock);
    while(rcvAux != NULL)
    {
        fflush(rsock);
        numCharsRcv += strlen(rcv);
        numLinesRcv++;
        printf("%s", rcv);
        rcvAux = fgets(rcv, MAXDATASIZE, rsock);
    }
    printf("%s", rcv);
    free(rcv);
}
```

It happens that writeProcess() works fine but readProcess() doesn't, apparently rsock gets an invalid memory address and I get Segmentation Fault.

---

Sorry, I have omitted some parts of the code, it would be very long.

Actually, I'm connecting the socket and the write function is working, but when it enters in the read function the file pointer loses its reference, at least I've seen this when  debugging with GDB.

This problem has started occurring just after I have added the threads, when it was running on a single process it was working just fine

Comment: For one thing, calling `fflush` on a FILE open for reading is undefined behavior... Even if it doesn't horribly crash it's not going to do what you want. Who taught you to use `fflush` like this?

Comment: @R..: good point! However, I believe it sets `errno` (EBADF?) instead. Not sure if it's really undefined. Anyway, I think that grants a real answer.

Comment: 7.19.5.2: "If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @R..: oh, I'm wrong :) Thanks for looking it up!!

Answer (score 4):

```
int sockfd;
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

The above creates a *disconnected* TCP socket.

```
rsock = fdopen(sockfd, "r");
wsock = fdopen(sockfd, "w");
```

These open the same disconnected socket as two dysfunctional `FILE*`.

You need two different connected sockets to start with.

If the code you posted is a complete program, I can't see how it is supposed to work. Both reader and writer start with `fgets()` which should block them forever, since there would be no data.

Answer (score 1):

Point 1 below is likely to be the real cause of your segmentation fault:

1. `fgets` appends a null character to the end of the stored string. This means that you have to pass `MAXDATASIZE-1` instead of `MAXDATASIZE`, otherwise an overflow may occur.
2. Some might claim your program is leaking memory because you're assigning the return of `fgets` to `rcvAux`, which itself was pointing to another memory address that you manually allocated. After this assignment you won't be able to `free` it because the address of that allocated memory is lost.
3. You are not checking the return values for `socket()` nor `fdopen()`. And you are not closing `sockfd` before exiting the application.

**Update**:

As pointed by [R..](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379897/r) in comments, using `fflush` on non-writeable file-descriptor is undefined behavior.

Your code snippet doesn't show any `connect()` or `bind()`+`listen()`+`accept()` either. Your socket should first be connected in order to perform read and/or write operations. Checking the return values of each operation would have caught that.

Comment: Even on a writable file descriptor, `fflush` is UB if it's in "reading mode" (if the last operation was a read). And to switch between reading/writing, you need an intervening successful seek operation.

Comment: Hmm, right. So one is only allowed to `fflush` if it's guaranteed the last operation on the fd was a write. Gotta go now, but later I'll update the answer to mention this. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Or if the file is newly opened or just had a successful seek (so it's doing neither reading nor writing). The important point is that if there's potentially-buffered data for reading, `fflush` is not allowed (you can think of the reason as being that `fflush` pertains to write buffers, whereas the buffers are tied up by read-mode).

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking if both fdopen() return good values, and bail if not.